# ESPAsyncWebServer how do you escape the % character?

Tags: programming

% characters are used for [template processing](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer#template-processing) but I want it to just send the % through. How do you tell it to do that?

Comment: Can you please add some more context. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use `%%` to get a single `%` as output.

From the source code: [double percent sign encountered, this is single percent sign escaped.](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer/blob/fc71230a31c25ddebec7462d60cd495c919244c8/src/WebResponses.cpp#L402)

Comment: Thank you. Biyaaaaaa!